# Does cocos2d-x support python

Tags: python, cocos2d-x

I think cocos2d-x should support python because it is a project forked from cocos2d. But according to their website, the only scripted languages they support are javascript and lua. So does it support python or not? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use python. You can use C++, javascript and Lua for development.

Cocos2d-x is a port of an Objective-C library which itself was a port of a Python library.

cocos2d, written in python language comes in starting of 2008 and after that in mid 2008 due to popularity of iphone, Cocos2D was ported to ObjectiveC for use on iOS. During the end of 2010 cocos2d-x comes that is written in C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not support python. Currently python is only used for compiling and generating in cocos2d-x. C++ and javascript are the best languages to develop with cocos2d-x, lua's documentation is poor and few developers are using it.